# Special character Android>Oracle-Linux

Tags: android, linux, oraclelinux

I got a web application running on a Oracle-Linux VM running in the Oracle Cloud. There are a mobile app (iOS/Android) that communicate with the webapp through a textual chat.
When I send a message from iOs to the webapp every character (specials too) is displayed on the browser, if I send a special character with an Android device I see only garbage.

Is someone able to explain why?

The db charset is utf8. Except this I really dont know where to put my hands, sorry for the lack of infos.